# Unable To Cast DataSet

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I Get Error While debugging the program, sayingUnable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataSet' to type MyDatabase.DataSet'

What Do I Need TO DO Fix It

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
    string strUser;
    string strPass;
    string sMsg = "";

    strUser = txtUserID.Text ;
    strPass = txtPassword.Text ;

    DataSet o_Find = new DataSet ();
    Users oUsers = new Users();

    try
    {
        o_Find = (DataSet)oUsers.FindData(strUser,strPass);
        sMsg = "Welcome " + o_Find.Tables ["Login"].Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString ();

        switch (strUser)
        {
            case "Admissions":
                frmAdmissions admitForm = new frmAdmissions ();
                admitForm.Visible = true;
                admitForm.Activate();
                break;
            case "Admin":
            case "Nurse":
            case "Doctor":
                frmMenu menuForm = new frmMenu ();
                menuForm.oCurrent.UserName = strUser;
                menuForm.Visible = true;
                menuForm.Activate();
                menuForm.SelectUser();
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to have others just do your legwork for you. What have you tried? The message is pretty explanatory here IMO

Comment: Compiler errors come with line numbers.  When seeking help, never divorce the error message from the line number. (and highlight said line in your code via a comment)

Comment: @KirkWoll: Although I certainly agree with you, it's pretty obvious that the o_find = (DataSet) line is part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in this line:

```
o_Find = (DataSet)oUsers.FindData(strUser,strPass);
```

It seems that you have overridden the meaning of DataSet somewhere in your code. (What is type `MyDatabase.DataSet`, for example?)

This should fix the problem:

```
o_Find = (System.Data.DataSet)oUsers.FindData(strUser,strPass);
```